# Getting spinner information

Tags: android, spinner

having a little problem getting the information from my spinner, this is how i have it set up in my activity

```
color = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.ledColor);
vibrate = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.vibPattern);

populateSpinners();

color.setOnItemSelectedListener(new colorSelected()); 
vibrate.setOnItemSelectedListener(new vibrateSelected());           

    public void populateSpinners(){
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> cAdapter;
    cAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.colors,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    int cSpinnerDD = android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item;
    cAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(cSpinnerDD);
    color.setAdapter(cAdapter);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> vAdapter;
    vAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.vibrate, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    int vSpinnerDD = android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item;
    vAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(vSpinnerDD);
    vibrate.setAdapter(vAdapter);
}

public class colorSelected implements OnItemSelectedListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
        arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        nColor = arg0.toString();
        Log.v("EditContact",nColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
/********************************************************************************************/
public class vibrateSelected implements OnItemSelectedListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
        arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        nVibrate = arg0.toString();
        Log.v("EditContact",nVibrate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

but it does not get the selection from the spinner what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to work with arguments named arg0, arg1, arg2.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a public method like this :

```
public String returnString(AdapterView<?> parent,int position,long ID){

    return parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }
```

and put it in your onItemSelected method :

```
     String yourtext = returnString(arg0, arg2, arg3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get spinner selected value by using below code..

```
String value=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```